# jQuery Syntax issue - css and multiple background positioning

Tags: jquery, css, background

I'm trying to adjust the background position of one of two backgrounds on `<body>` using CSS3's multiple background property. I need to update a position with jQuery and I'm very stuck! I have the integer in a variable but it won't work, I think my concatenation is wrong...

```
$('body.home').css( "background-position" , 
                    "top center, center" + bottomBackgroundOffset  );
```

I also need some sort of listener (I think that's the correct term) so that if the window size changes it triggers this code, this is because the background image will need to update it's position. Don't ask why I'm doing this, it's a last resort..!

Comment: Concatenation looks fine .. are you sure `bottomBackgroundOffset` is set?

Comment: yes, should be. More code here;

`var pageHeight = $('body').height();
var footerHeight = $('#footer').height();
var bottomBackgroundOffset = pageHeight + footerHeight;`

Comment: Are you wanting to change it when they scroll? If so use this http://api.jquery.com/scroll/ You need an event handler assigned somewhere to trigger your code.

Comment: No, it's got to be fixed to the bottom of the page, it spans the whole width and due to restrictions I can't put the background on the footer.

Comment: @Dan Bellow is the event trigger you're looking for I think.  I see that you said "if the window size changes," so just use the wrapper bellow and stick what ever code you need inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For on `resize()` do:

```
$(window).resize(function() { 
     $('body.home').css( "background-position" , "top center, center " + bottomBackgroundOffset + "px" );
});
```

Of course you need to set your `var bottomBackgroundOffset;` first, which I'm assuming you're already doing.

See [API Doc](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) for more info.

Comment: Looks good, but it doesn't explain why this won't work at the moment. I could do with getting that first...

Comment: @Dan Well give more code then. From just that snippet I'd say it's because its set only once and never again because it's never triggered after the first time.

Comment: I think it's my crappy code. Something is wrong because this works

`$('body.home').css( "background-position" , "top center, center 1515px"  );`

Comment: @Dan I think I see what you might be doing wrong. See update. You need to add `"px"` to the string. I even missed that on first look, also add a blank space after `center`.

Comment: Ah, simple and spot on. Thanks for your time and help. Also, when I said about the resize, I meant body I think - it's incase something opens on a page causing it to get longer and therefore I need to adjust this background position - I hope it makes sense.

Surely I could use $('body').resize ..?

Comment: jQuery alone wont, you need a plug in for that. Use this one http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/ then you could do `$("#myID").resize(...`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax in JQuery 1.11.1 min is a little different. It takes the two URL between one quote. The same in backgroundSize and backgroundPosition:

```
.css('backgroundImage', 'url(fileadmin/creusen/Creusen-Hintergrund4-L.jpg) ,       
                         url(fileadmin/creusen/Creusen-Hintergrund4-R.jpg)');
```